# delphi android manage HorzScrollBox left and right in a VertScrollBox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

i have to use a `HorzScrollBox` in main `VertScrollBox` as a card view.
the problem is just one of scrollBoxes working at same time.

you can see the view in screenshot.there are some `HorzScrollBox` in a VertScrollBox...

[image]

when i set `HitTest` to true for `HorzScrollBox` then it scroll left and right but `VertScrollBox` dont scrolling up and down and if i set `HitTest` to false then just `VertScrollBox` working.

how can i fix this and what strategy i must use to handle user scroll ?

Comment: Have you considered one `TScrollBox` and the cards directly on that. It can scroll in all directions.

Comment: in this case all lines scroll with each other? this dont look pretty also isnt like android native card view..

Comment: Ok, understood. Is this correct:*...when i set `HitTest` to true for `HorzScrollBox` then it dont scroll left and right...*? Should it not be the other way around? Anyway, sorry but I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: @TomBrunberg fixed the typo.i searched for a solution  all over the web and dont found anything :| its amazing any one dont used a cardview in firemonkey app!!

Comment: the problem is because the `HitTest` have true or false to just catch the click or just pass the click.if it be possible to do both the problem resolve.i mean the click sent to both `HorzScrollBox` and `VertScrollBox` then `HorzScrollBox` do action in X axis and `VertScrollBox` do in Y axis!!